# how to send server response.cookie and response.render together?

Tags: node.js, http, express, cookies, response

```
app.get("/auth/google", passport.authenticate("google", {
    session: false,
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
}));

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: " x",
        clientSecret: " y",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, Gprofile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {

            Gdata = {
                'id': Gprofile.id,
                'name': Gprofile.displayName,
                'profileImage': Gprofile.photos[0].value,
                'gender': Gprofile.gender,
                'email': Gprofile.emails[0].value
            };

            console.log('Gdata recieved');
            console.log('--------------------------------------------------------------------------');

            return done(null, true); //It seems redirects to failureRedirect or successRedirect.
        });
    }
));

app.get("/auth/google/callback", passport.authenticate('google', {
    session: false,
    failureRedirect: "/google_callback_fail",
    successRedirect: "/reports"
}));

app.get("/reports", function(req, res) {
    // ------------DB
    var db = require('../model/connection.js');
    var stmt;

    var name = Gdata.name.split(" ");
    stmt = "INSERT INTO User( `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES (?,?,?)";


    var x = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var sentToCJS;
        db.query(stmt, [name[0], name[1], Gdata.email], function(err, rows) {
            if (err) reject(err);

            PAYLOAD = { userID: rows.insertId };

            ENCODED_JWT = _jwt.sign(PAYLOAD, 'secret', { expiresIn: EXP_TIME });
            console.log("1 ENCODED_JWT:", ENCODED_JWT);


            sentToCJS = {
                'jwt': ENCODED_JWT,
                'name': Gdata.name,
                'profileImage': Gdata.profileImage,
                'gender': Gdata.gender,
                'email': Gdata.email
            };
            console.log("sentToCJS:", sentToCJS);

            //creates persistant cookie.
               res.cookie("jwt", ENCODED_JWT, {
                maxAge: 604800, //7days to ms
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: true,
                signed: true //detects if user has modified the cookie
            });

            resolve(sentToCJS);
        });

    });

    x.then(function(sentToCJS) {
        res.render('reports', sentToCJS);
    });


    x.catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    });
```

**Desired result: Server responses cookie and renders('reports', sentToCJS);
res.cookie and res.render needs to work.**

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent**

How can I send res.cookie and res.render together or in multiple responses? 
It seems not possible with express but it's possible with node.js res.write or writeHead method.

Comment: Those two statements are part of a single response. What do you mean by two response?

Comment: @Muthukumar I updated the error message

Answer (score 0):

`res.cookie()` just queues the cookie for the eventual response with other headers (it's the same type of operation as [`res.setHeader()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)) so the code you show will send both the cookie and the render.  It should work as you already have it.

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. at SendStream.headers Already Sent

Now that you've just recently added that you are seeing this particular error being reported, there is something else going on in your code.  The two function calls you show in your question will NOT, by themselves, cause this error.  That error is usually caused by incorrect handling of some asynchronous operation in your request handler.  Chances are, you are calling `res.render()` BEFORE the async operation has completed and then when the async operation completes, you try to then send the headers, but it's too late because you've already rendered the page and sent the response and you can't send more than one response per request.

To help you fix your code, we need to see the code for the entire request handler that contains these two function calls and then we can likely help you with the correct fix.   Without seeing the code, all we can say is that you probably have an error in how you're handling an asynchronous operation inside the request handler.

Comment: @21wesd34eqwfsdv - That error message is not caused by only the lines of code you show.  That it typically caused by an error in how you handle some asynchronous operation where you are sending one part of your response at the wrong time.  We would need to see all the code for this request handler to show you were you've made that error.  But, the two function calls you show one after another like this will NOT cause the error you say all by themselves.  There is other code involved in causing that error.

Comment: @21wesd34eqwfsdv - Added summary to my answer of what we know now until you include more code.

Comment: @jfriend00 added major detail.  and updated my question . The problem seems to be sending two responses.

Comment: @Internial - Are you the same person who posted the original question here?  If so, you should edit it when you're logged in as the same user that you posted the question as.  Right now, the edit is waiting to be approved because the system thinks it was edited by someone besides the person who wrote the original question.